# How to modify specific field in ndarray matrix

Tags: python

I have a matrix like this

```
x = [[a, b],
     [c, d]]
```

But instead of a,b,c,d for each of those values there's a list  of numbers, for example [x, xx, xxx].

I would like to create another matrix that would have ones only on positions where x==0 && xx==0 && xxx==0. How can I do that without loops? For example, I could do B = [x == 0], but how can I do that where there's a list instead of single matrix element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is of fixed length, you can create a 3d array and then use `np.all()` on its last axis:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.zeros((2, 2, 3)) # 2x2 matrix, 3 variants for each element

In [3]: a[0, 0] = [0, 1, 2] # filling one element of the "matrix"

In [4]: a[0, 1] = 1

In [5]: a[1, 1] = 0 # this

In [6]: a[1, 0] = 0 # and this are "all zeros"

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Now let's construct the matrix `b`:

```
In [8]: np.all(a == 0, axis=-1).astype(int)
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

If you want another condition, you can modify the expression in the following way:

```
In [9]: np.all(a - [0, 1, 2] == 0, axis=-1).astype(int)
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is to check if x==0, xx==0 and xxx=0, is that right? But what if I want different conditions for each of them? For example, x==0, xx==3, xxx=7? And could you explain a bit how this works, I'm new to python, so I don't really get the idea behind this? What will happen (step by step) when you do this?

Comment: @pera, I added an example that checks for `[0, 1, 2]` instead. To understand what's going on you can try evaluating parts of this expression in an interactive shell. You'll see that `a - [0, 1, 2]` is an array the same shape as `a` with `[0, 1, 2]` subtracted "along the last axis", and `a - [0, 1, 2] == 0` is a boolean array of the same shape. Then `np.all()` collapses it along the last axis to produce a 2d boolean array. We then convert it to `int` using `astype`.